# Using binder clips to hold cables

Tags: office-supplies, cables

I'm looking to use binder clips to hold cables from falling behind my desk, and I have seen life hacks on this. The one thing I have not found is how to select the right one for the job. The surface I would be attaching the clip to is 1.8cm or just under 3/4 of an inch.

Answer (score 7):

You're right, I don't think there IS a right-size clip for this. I have an 18mm desktop too and the medium-sized clip (32mm wide) won't fit. If it DID fit, the lever part would be too big for most cables - they would drop right through.

So we need to be using the smaller clips - and that means a thinner (very thin) desktop. The only thing I can suggest is that you try using the BIGGEST clip to attach a piece of cardboard or plywood to the desk surface - then have the smallest clips on that piece of thin board to hold the cables.

EDIT: I was quite impressed with this that I just found on Google Images. I shows that the largest clips CAN be used but in a slightly different way:

[image]

Comment: The picture shows what I thought was the obvious way. If that is different from what you had in mind, I would like to know what that was?

Comment: @MadsSkjern It's leaving the lever folded BACK with the cable going through the "loop" . The cable is hanging loose and it is easy to pull the plug towards phone/tablet when needed, then let it fall back to its rest position when not in use. Ideally, the plug on the cable will be too big to pass through the loop, but the cable will move freely; you would have to remove and reattach the lever in order to get the cable through the loop. A picture speaks a thousand words, just Google Image search "bulldog clip cable tidy" and you will see many photos.

Answer (score 2):

To my experience these clips do *not* come in a great variety of sizes, which could give you a little problem. However as long as you have one which is too large it is simply a matter of attaching something beneath the surface to make it a better fit.

You could either fold up some paper or cardboard or even a strip of wood, and put this below the desk so it is not visible. This should make the standard sizes of clips an easy fit to your desk.

Comment: You mean like a shim